# Vala OpenGL glGenTexture

Tags: opengl, sdl, vala

```
colors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
if (colors == 4) {   // alpha
    if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGBA;
    else
        texture_format = GL_BGRA;
} else {             // no alpha
    if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        format = GL_RGB;
    else
        format = GL_BGR;
}

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, colors, surface->w, surface->h, 0,
                    texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
```

I am trying to convert that code I found on Stack Overflow to Vala. However, I'm having trouble with glGenTextures.

The first part was straightforward:

```
    int texture_format;
    uchar colors = screen.format.BytesPerPixel;
    if (colors == 4) {
        if (screen.format.Rmask == 0x000000ff) {
            texture_format = GL_RGBA;
        } else {
            texture_format = GL_BGRA;
        }
    } else {
        if (screen.format.Rmask == 0x000000ff) {
            texture_format = GL_RGB;
        } else {
            texture_format = GL_BGR;
        }
    }
```

This, part, though, I don't know how to convert:
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);

I tried:

```
    GL.GLuint[] texture = {};
    glGenTextures (1, texture);
```

I got:

```
.vala:46.27-46.33: error: Argument 2: Cannot pass value to reference or output parameter
```

I also tried:

```
GL.GLuint[] texture = {};
glGenTextures (1, out texture);
```

I got:

```
ERROR:valaccodearraymodule.c:1183:vala_ccode_array_module_real_get_array_length_cvalue: assertion failed: (_tmp48_)
```

I tried:

```
glGenTextures (1, &texture);
```

I got:

```
.vala:46.27-46.34: error: Argument 2: Cannot pass value to reference or output parameter
```

I tried various other similar things, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the binding is wrong.  Based on [the glGenTextures man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenTextures.xml), the Vala binding should be something like:

```
public static void glGenTextures ([CCode (array_length_pos = 0.9)] GL.GLuint[] textures);
```

The proper way to call it would be something like:

```
GL.GLuint[] textures = new GL.GLuint[1];
glGenTextures (textures);
// your texture is textures[0]
```

Of course that's not very nice for the use case you're looking at where you just want a single textures, but it's not that big of a deal.  The problem is that you have to allocate an array on the heap...  I don't doubt this is a performance-sensitive area of code, so I probably wouldn't bother, but you could always create an alternate version:

```
[CCode (cname = "glGenTextures")]
public static void glGenTexture (GL.GLsizei n, out GL.GLuint texture);
```

Which you could then call with

```
GL.GLuint texture;
glGenTexture (1, out texture);
```

In spite of the fact that you can only use this version to generate a single texture you still have to pass the first argument manually.

Comment: That worked perfectly. The only problem now is surface.pixels returns a `void*`, but `glTexImage2D();` calls for a `GL.GLvoid[]?`. Any ideas on how to fix that on the gl.vapi? Thanks!

Comment: Casting should work.  `glTexImage2D (..., (GL.GLvoid[]) surface.pixels);`.  That said, `GL.GLvoid[]?` is probably wrong for the argument--it should probably be void*, GL.GLvoid (and GL.GLvoid should be a class not a struct), uint8[] (used for binary data), or if the pixel format is well-defined something more specific (e.g., a 2-dimensional array of some pixel type).  Unless you've seen this done somewhere you'll likely want to find some detailed documentation of SDL and OpenGL to make sure that the formats are compatible... trying to put RGBA in a BGR buffer will not turn out well.